# Tiny Tiny RSS Installation

Tags: rss

I am having difficulties in installing the following:
http://tt-rss.org/redmine/

I keep constantly getting this error after my installation (Which obviously,  isn't correct).
Fatal Error: config: please read config.php completely.

I would much appreciate it if someone would install this for me!
I will happily give FTP details :)

Please, I really need this.
Thanks.

Comment: Ill just install this on my own server and then I'll let you know any pitfalls I see. Please don't ever give your FTP details to a stranger.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read through the config.php completely?
On line 184 there is an "isconfigured" option, you will get the error you have described if this is not set to true. This seems to have been added by the author as a check that you have read and understood the config file. Also the config defaults to use postgres you will almost certainly need to change this to MYSQL.

> 3 define('DB_TYPE', "pgsql"); // or mysql
>   ...
>   184 define('ISCONFIGURED', false);
>   185 // Please set this to true if you have read everything above and
>   186 // finished setting configuration options.

If you issue is not either of these give some more details.

Comment: Geez, how did I miss that?  Your answer helped me with tt-rss, even if the OP didn't bother to reply.  The author of these packages can be annoying at times...